# DC/DC converter in parallel with analog circuit

Tags: dc, circuit-design, impedance-matching

I have a DC/DC converter that takes 6.3 V and converts it to 900 V. I am attempting to run it in parallel with an analog circuit that runs at 12 V (see below).

Without the analog circuit in parallel the DC/DC converter works fine. As soon as the extra circuit is added in the voltage drops to some 0.45 Vdc for the input of the converter.

The dcdc converter is a pcb element (EMCO q15-12). At full load it is drawing 7mA.

Is this some type of impedance matching issue? Something else?  My main focus is physics. I am relatively new to advanced circuit design.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fADa3R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Please tell me you aren't really supplying that DCDC converter through a 500k potentiometer ... or through a potentiometer or resistive voltage divider of any sort ...

Comment: The converter is a small pcb mount element.  The current is nC. Is this not ok with the newly given information?

Comment: First, I found it pretty shocking to see an arbitrary DCDC converter that takes 6.3VDC and mysteriously creates 900VDC from it. That's pretty impressive and may require a number of stages in a practical design. Can you identify the part for us?

Comment: It's an EMCO Q15-12. It is a proportional DC to HVDC converter.
[link](http://www.emcohighvoltage.com/proportional/qseries.php)

Comment: The exact voltage will be dependent upon the unit used.  6.3 vdc is not the concern. What I need is to keep a desired low voltage. I am not getting that

Comment: as far as I understand, that Q15 would pull "less than 40mA", ie. worst-case 40mA, right?

Comment: Yes, it is a very low current requirement on my backend.

Comment: Oh and pardon me nA...Too much coffee this am. I guess nC/s would have worked haha

Comment: 40mA * 250 kOhm = 40*250 V = 10.000 V>> 12V?!

Comment: where do you take the nA from?

Comment: It is using nA for a detector. The detector usually pulls almost no current

Comment: yes, but you're assuming your converter has 100% efficiency, then, right? I'd assume it'd have more like 1%...

Comment: i.e. can you test, for the working case, how much current the primary side of your converter *actually* draws?

Comment: What is the 12V source impedance?

Comment: 7mA at full load

Comment: No, I'm curious if the 12V source voltage might change with different loading on it. So if your added circuit might cause the voltage to droop lower. Have you measured the voltage at the top or take-off point of the potentiometer divider after the circuit is added?

Comment: Do some simple Ohm's law with that 7mA figure and whatever you have that 500k pot set to. Imagine the 'top half' of the pot is 237.5k (and the 'bottom-half' is 262.5k). What 'should' the voltage drop acros the top half be if you really did have 7mA flowing through it? Now do you see why using a pot or any other kind of simple resistive voltage divider is not a good idea? Do as Tony suggests in his answer and run your DCDC from a linear regulator like a LM317.

Comment: YOur problem is the high starting excitation current and if it can not start oscillating at 0.7V your primary winding is dropping the voltage to 0.45 and not oscillating , ... which will increase input impedance thru primary due to commutating current thru primary. So a large series cap + to 12V and - to input would help kick start it.  I once designed a 15kV regulator for Lexmark Laser printer drums using a resonant LC step up converter with no EMI or shields in a similar small size.

Answer (score 1):

The important detail is "It's an EMCO Q15-12"

This is a 1.5kV output with DC control and operates from 12V

IT is rated for 1.25W and so you should operate from 12Vdc and use a pot to control the output voltage via the control input as shown in the datasheet.
[datasheet](http://www.emcohighvoltage.com/datasheets/qseries.pdf)

If this is an option you don't have use a 1W LDO such as a LM317 to control the voltage with a suitable pot and fixed resistors to control the Input voltage from 2-10V to get 0.2-1 kV out.

To speed up the decay time you may consider applying a 1W resistor rated for 2kV or 4x500V equal 1/4W resistors in the range of 250k to 1 M

your voltage source impedance must be < 1% for 1% load regulation.
If 1.2W at 12V input average impedance is 120 Ohms so your regulator impedance needs to be ~1 Ohm

If you are only consuming 0.1W then the source impedance can be 10 Ohms.
A voltage regulator with 500mA drive capacity at 12V and drops only 0.1 V has an ESR of 0.1A/0.5A or 200 mOhm for example and easily satisfies the load regulation you desire.

The real impedance of the converter on surge startup depends on its primary winding DCR so startup current can drop your high impedance source below its required startup voltage of 0.7V ( Vbe ) which is why your circuit failed.

Comment: The part number with the control option should have a 'C' in the second grouping; maybe OP isn't using a controllable version. Also the control looks really poor if the converter is lightly loaded (his nanoamp comment is worrying)

Comment: I am using a pot to control it. The unit is pulling ~7mA with my back end detector using no where near a microA.

Comment: I will try a voltage regulator ahead of Pot in the circuit. Thanks

Comment: If you just wanted a pot use <=1k with a cap between 12V and tap using an RC time constant equal or longer than the output RC response. Even a Darlington buffer would work to reduce output impedance Rpot/hFE

Answer (score 1):

I eventually used a Texas Instruments TPS7A4700 positive adjustable linear voltage regulator evaluation board to control the input voltage to the EMCO unit. The detector works and was used on the International Space Station to map the radiation environment in low-earth orbit.  This option was more expensive than discrete parts. But the time saved by buying this unit allowed us to ship the detector to NASA earlier.